# How to use github actions bot for testing gradle java

Tags: kotlin, gradle, junit4, github-actions, gradlew

I am trying to implement Github-actions(bot), which runs gradle test when PR has been created.
To assure that my workflow file works as I expected, I explicitly wrote a test method which should cause failure.

```kotlin
@Test
fun thisShouldFail() {
    assertEquals(1, 2)
}
```

When I try testing on my local machine, I get the log below.

```
> Task :test FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

# More
```

Above log indicates that there was something wrong in the test codes as I expected it to be.
But then Github actions bot runs this command, the test code result is `SUCCESS`.

Below is my github workflow yaml file for this action.

```yaml
name: PullRequestGradleTest

on:
  pull_request_target:
    types: [labeled]

jobs:
  test:
    name: GradleTest
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: contains(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, 'STAGING')

    steps:
      - name: checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup JDK 1.8
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          java-version: '8'
          distribution: 'adopt'

      - name: Grant Permissions to gradlew
        run: chmod +x gradlew
      - name: Test
        run: gradle test --tests "*"

      - name: Test Success
        if: success()
        uses: actions/github-script@0.2.0
        with:
          github-token: ${{ github.token }}
          script: |
            const pull_number = "${{github.event.number}}"
            await github.pulls.createReview({
              ...context.repo,
              pull_number,
              body: "All tests passed.",
              event: "APPROVE"
            })
      - name: Test Fail
        if: failure()
        uses: actions/github-script@0.2.0
        with:
          github-token: ${{ github.token }}
          script: |
            const pull_number = "${{github.event.number}}"
            await github.pulls.createReview({
              ...context.repo,
              pull_number,
              body: "There is something wrong with test codes.",
             event: "REQUEST_CHANGES"
            })
            await github.pulls.update({
              ...context.repo,
              pull_number,
              state: "closed"
            })
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that you are using `gradle`, not `gradlew`.

```yaml
name: PullRequestGradleTest

on:
  pull_request_target:
    types: [labeled]

jobs:
  test:
    name: GradleTest
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: contains(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, 'STAGING')

    steps:
      - name: checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup JDK 1.8
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          java-version: '8'
          distribution: 'adopt'

      - name: Grant Permissions to gradlew
        run: chmod +x gradlew
      - name: Test
        run: ./gradlew test --tests "*"

      - name: Test Success
        if: success()
        uses: actions/github-script@0.2.0
        with:
          github-token: ${{ github.token }}
          script: |
            const pull_number = "${{github.event.number}}"
            await github.pulls.createReview({
              ...context.repo,
              pull_number,
              body: "All tests passed.",
              event: "APPROVE"
            })
      - name: Test Fail
        if: failure()
        uses: actions/github-script@0.2.0
        with:
          github-token: ${{ github.token }}
          script: |
            const pull_number = "${{github.event.number}}"
            await github.pulls.createReview({
              ...context.repo,
              pull_number,
              body: "There is something wrong with test codes.",
             event: "REQUEST_CHANGES"
            })
            await github.pulls.update({
              ...context.repo,
              pull_number,
              state: "closed"
            })
```

If you use `gradle` in the command, it will depend on the machine's environment. In this case, there is a possibility that occurs error because of `Gradle` version. Therefore, you need to use the project's `Gradle` which is included with your repo. The way to use is using `gradlew` scripts.

I also recommend following these three steps to test the branch for the pull request.

> Clean -> Assemble(or build) -> Test

Comment: Great! Actually changed from `./gradlew test` to `gradle test` because I also thought that something was wrong with gradle, but it wasn't the root cause of this problem. :)

Comment: Then, you might need to provide detailed information like showing exception message or stacktrace to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Base problem was that if we use `pull_request_target` event, the action runs on the target branch, which would be the base branch that the PR will be merged into. To solve this problem, I had to explicitly set where this action will run on.

On `job` => `steps`

```yaml
steps:
      - name: checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }}
          repository: ${{github.event.pull_request.head.repo.full_name }}
```